# I want to add a class to the web project that will do some PDF creation

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the class I am creating visible to the client.  I have the following class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Test1.Web
{
    [EnableClientAccess]
    public class CreatePDF  
    {


        public string paragraph { get; set; }
        public CreatePDF()
        { }

        public void GoGoGadgetPDF()
        {
            var document = new Document();
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("PDFs");
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + "/document.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph(paragraph));
            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I put the class directly beneath the Web Project in the folder structure i.e.

- Test1.Web

  - References
  - ClientBin (folder)
  - Models (folder)
  - CreatedPDF.cs
  - Authentication.cs

I can get access to my DomainService class in the models folder and the Authentication.cs class.  But not the CreatePDF.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer.  My RIA Services needs nothing to do with the PDF creation.  I added a WCF Service and used that instead.